# Clarifying Understanding of Fields

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, field

I'm currently learning C# in Unity through a series of video tutorials and just had fields introduced. Am I correct in saying that fields are just variables declared in the class level?

Comment: That is totally correct -- and a tutorial that fails to explain that fields are *variables* is maybe not the best tutorial. Something to think about is *what else is and is not a variable*?  Is a property a variable? Is an array element a variable? Is a formal parameter a variable? What about an `out` parameter? What about a `const` or a `readonly`? What do you think, and can you justify your opinion? By going through this sort of exercise you can get at the essential nature of what makes a thing a *variable*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can say this.

The main difference is that variables in methods (also called local variables) have a temporary value used during the method call. The next time you call the method the previous value of the variables are lost and you have to initialize them again. (I am not talking about advanced stuff like iterators and captured variables.)

On the other side, variables in classes and structs, i.e. **fields**, are living as long as the object lives. I.e., they keep their value between method calls.

Unlike local variables that are first undefined, fields are assigned a default value when an object is created from a class. Struct fields behave differently depending whether the struct is used as class field or variable. The struct fields have thee same definedness as the field or variable defining them.

---

As @elgonzo commented, there are two types of fields

- Static fields. They are declared with the `static` modifier. Static fields exist exactly once for a specific class or struct, independently of the number of objects of this type.
- Instance fields exist once per object (i.e. class or struct instance).

Private instance fields can only be accessed by instance methods and constructors of this class or struct, where as private static fields can be accessed by static and instance methods and constructors. (Methods include getters and setters of properties and indexers.)

Example. With this class...

```
public class A
{
    private static int _staticCounter;
    private int _instanceCounter;

    public void Count()
    {
        _staticCounter++;
        _instanceCounter++;
    }

    public void PrintCount()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Static = {_staticCounter}, Instance = {_instanceCounter}");
    }

    public static void PrintStatic()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Static = {_staticCounter}"); // Can only access static fields.
    }
}
```

...this test...

```
A x = new A();
A y = new A();

x.Count();
x.Count();
y.Count();
y.Count();
y.Count();

x.PrintCount();
y.PrintCount();
A.PrintStatic();
Console.ReadKey();
```

...prints this to the console

```
Static = 5, Instance = 2
Static = 5, Instance = 3
Static = 5
```

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that the answer here talks about "instance fields/variables" (or "object variables"), which are associated with instances/objects of a given type (class). "Class variables" - as the name implies - are static fields, associated with the type (class) itself and independent of any object instance...

Comment: A little bit more nitpicking (hey, it's weekend, and i am in a good mood ;-b ): As long as their access modifier is `public` or `internal`, instance fields can not only be accessed by instance methods within the class/struct, but also from "outside" (of course requiring a reference to an object instance they are associated with). Okay, okay, i'll go now and enjoy my weekend.. :-)

Comment: Therefore I said "within the class/struct", meaning this as restriction for the said methods. I reworded it for clarification.

Comment: In addition to instance variables and static variables, it's also possible to create thread variables using the `ThreadStatic` attribute ([ThreadLocal<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadlocal-1) is a wrapper around `ThreadStatic` that is a bit easier to use).  Contrary to the name, `ThreadStatic` variables can be instance variables (one per accessing thread per instance) or static variables (one per accessing thread).  This may seem like an advanced tool, but it can be useful for wrapping services that lack thread-safety (e.g., `Random`).

Comment: Note that `ThreadStatic` is not supported by Unity.  Per [the official documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Attributes.html), using `ThreadStatic` will cause Unity to crash.  However, I think [this was fixed](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/e-document-threadstatic-attribute-must-not-be-used-i-will-cause-crashes) in Unity 4.3